# Commutator and Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, commutator

> Assume that $[\hat{A},\hat{H}]_-=0$ and $[\hat{B},\hat{H}]_-=0$ but we know that $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]_-\neq 0$. Then there exists degenerate stationary states of $H$. How to prove it?

Comment: Hint: Use that commuting operators are simultaneously diagonalizable, and non-commuting ones are not.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure that is my way is correct to proove it while using your hint. If $\hat{A},\hat{B},\hat{H}$ is a matrix and additionaly there are $[\hat{A},\hat{H}]_- \iff AH=HA \iff A=H^{-1}AH$ 
analogical $B=H^{-1}BH$
Then I can write $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]_-=AB-BA=H^{-1}AH H^{-1}BH - H^{-1}BHH^{-1}AH = H^{-1}ABH - H^{-1}BAH $
Now I have a problem with rewriting them in diagonalized state. Is it ok: $A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}A_1&0&0\\0&A_2&0\\0&0&A_3\end{array}\right]$ and analogical with other matrix?

Comment: Please define the notation $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]_-$. Does this just mean commutator? I'm not used to the minus sign.

Comment: Yes, it typically means commutator

Answer (score 2):

> How to prove it?

**EDIT: Consider a state $|\psi_n\rangle$, which is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian $H$ having eigenvalue $E_n$.**

Then consider the action of $H$ on these two other states:

$$
|\alpha\rangle \equiv AB|\psi_n\rangle
$$

and
$$
|\beta\rangle \equiv BA|\psi_n\rangle
$$

**EDIT: Ask yourself: Are these eigenstate of the Hamiltonian? If so, to what eigenvalue do they correspond?**

Secondly, note that since $A$ and $B$ don't commute that means 
$$
|\alpha\rangle \neq |\beta \rangle
$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this. Where did you use $H$ operator?

Comment: @Prometherion - What is $H |\alpha\rangle$ and $H |\beta\rangle$?

Comment: I dont understand because I've never used Bra-Ket notation. I only know that $|\alpha \rangle $ is a vector of states. I can only go by my intuition and write that $H|\alpha \rangle = HBA |\psi \rangle = BHA |\psi \rangle = BAH|\psi \rangle$
I used a fact that $A,H$ and $B,H$ commutes.

Comment: Edited based on comments to make it a little more clear. Changed the definition of psi to be an eigenstate which also makes this a little more obvious, but I don't want to literally be doing your homework for you...

Comment: Ok, thx. I did it.